# Get all visible rows using Bootstrap Table

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-table

Bootstrap Table has a [method](http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/documentation/#methods) to get all hidden rows:

> getRowsHidden;    boolean;  Get all rows hidden and if you pass the show
> parameter true the rows will be shown again, otherwise, the method
> only will return the rows hidden.

It also has

> getHiddenColumns  -   Get hidden columns.
>
> getVisibleColumns -   Get visible columns

But how can I get **all visible rows**, using a combo of BT methods, or JQuery?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you still need this, but I managed to get all the data from both visible and hidden columns. The trick here is to set your hidden columns after the data has been loaded.

```
$("#TestTable").bootstrapTable({
    data: testData
}).bootstrapTable("hideColumn", "HiddenVals");
```

Then you can call your `$("#TestTable").bootstrapTable("getData");`

Here's a sample of this: https://jsfiddle.net/Musikero31/ebqsyqsr/

Answer (score 0):

[Bootstrap Table](http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/documentation) has a [getData](http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/documentation/#methods) method which gives you the currently visible rows as an array.

```
var visibleRows = $('#your-table-id').bootstrapTable('getData');
```

Comment: But it still needs to cater for those which are not visible `data-visible="false"`

Answer (score 0):

Stumbled upon similar problem. According to my testing 'getData' gives you the columns that were included at initialization. I was using json from server to init my data. I had to manually append uninitialized columns and it worked! So I was getting whole data now but I had to figure out how to filter visible data. Here is my solution bellow:

```
// Find visible fields
function FindVisibleFields() {
  var columns = $('#table').bootstrapTable('getVisibleColumns');
  var fields = [];
  for (var index in columns){
    fields.push(columns[index].field);
  }
  return fields;
}
```

Happy coding!